# Clion, CMake undefined reference to functions from libraries

Tags: c++, cmake, mingw, clion

I am trying to use assimp on windows using CLion,
but when I try to use the functions provided, I am met with

```
undefined reference to 'Assimp::Importer::ReadFile(char const*, unsigned int)'
```

error.

My current cmake.txt links the library like so:

```
    find_package(assimp REQUIRED)

    target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} assimp::assimp)
```

The assimp package was also installed using CLion's vcpkg.
The version of MinGW I'm trying to run on is 6.0, but 11.0 doesn't work either.

Comment: Can you verify that the result variable from find_library has been populated? If on 3.18 or later you can use the REQUIRED keyword in addition.

Comment: "I am using CLion, but the library and .dll were both built using visual studio.. is that a problem?" - If in Clion you use e.g. MinGW compiler, then it is the problem: Visual Studio libraries (note on `vc143` component in the library name) cannot be used for MinGW.

Comment: @firmament: Would the library not found, the variable `ASSIMP_LIBRARY` will contain NOTFOUND. In that case the call to `target_link_libraries`, which uses `${ASSIMP_LIBRARY}`, will emit an error.

Comment: @Tsyvarev well I have tried using CLion's vcpkg, so now I use `find_package(assimp REQUIRED)` and including assimp::assimp libraries, but still with the same error as before.. So I don't think it is a MinGW compiler problem..?

Comment: Please, update the question post with your new code. The current one has a little value: it uses a library, built for Visual Studio, with gcc compiler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after about a day of fiddling with this, I found out that assimp (probably) doesn't support mingw on windows.

ref:

- https://www.reddit.com/r/opengl/s/gr8P1Z5Ijt
- https://github.com/assimp/assimp/blob/master/Build.md

### The "fix":

In the end I changed the compiler from MinGW to VS2022 (visual studio 2022).

*Thank you all for the help!*

edit:
From what a friend told me, he got it working with MinGW after building with clang.